# When to use multiple ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In one of our microservices, we have three `@KafkaListener` methods, listening to three different topics, and they are all in same consumer group, like so:

```
    @KafkaListener(clientIdPrefix = "MicroServiceNameFromWhichItIsConsuming1",
                   topics = "${path1.to.topic.in.yaml}",
                   autoStartup = "${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-startup}",
                   groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
            public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record) throws Exception {
            log.info("Record Received MicroServiceNameFromWhichItIsConsuming1 " + "Key: " + record.key() + "Offset " + record.offset());
}

    @KafkaListener(clientIdPrefix = "MicroServiceNameFromWhichItIsConsuming2",
                   topics = "${path2.to.topic.in.yaml}",
                   autoStartup = "${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-startup}",
                   groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
            public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record) throws Exception {
            log.info("Record Received MicroServiceNameFromWhichItIsConsuming2 " + "Key: " + record.key() + "Offset " + record.offset());
}

    @KafkaListener(clientIdPrefix = "MicroServiceNameFromWhichItIsConsuming3",
                   topics = "${path3.to.topic.in.yaml}",
                   autoStartup = "${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-startup}",
                   groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
            public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record) throws Exception {
            log.info("Record Received MicroServiceNameFromWhichItIsConsuming3 " + "Key: " + record.key() + "Offset " + record.offset());
}
```

In consumer config class, we have definde `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` in following manner:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
    
        return factory;
}
```

According to this [article](https://medium.com/lydtech-consulting/kafka-consumer-group-rebalance-1-of-2-7a3e00aa3bb4), having three `@KafkaListner` methods referencing same consumer group can be a potential problem since:

> If a service has multiple consumers that subscribe to mutually
> exclusive topics but that share the same group.id then any rebalance
> triggered by any one consumer would still affect the other consumers
> in the group.
>
> When Consumer A eventually completes its poll and rejoins the consumer
> group, a further rebalance is triggered, and again all processing
> stops as partitions are revoked and reassigned. It can therefore be
> prudent to define separate consumer groups for consumers listening to
> different topics

Q0:

Will usage of `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor` alleviate issue when rebalance occurs?

So If I place different consumer groups in `groupId` within `@KafkaListener` would that solve a problem?

Q1:

Why should or should I not, have three different `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` referenced in `containerFactory` within `@KafkaListener` (each annotation its own `containerFactory`)? What is the role of `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`? And what is the role of `containerGroup` witihn `@KafkaListener`?

Q2:

I'm 95% sure that each of these topics will be consisted of three partitions.

Let's say that we have one instance of that microservice and that I did separate `@KafkaListener` methods in three different consumer groups. Should I in that case, for each `containerFactory` set `concurrency=3`? Then, number of `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` is equal to `concurrency`? Should that be most optimal to have one `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` (created by `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`) per partition, for a given topic? On the other, hand if Kubernetes/OpenShift/whatever decides to scale and bring up one more instance of microservice, I will have idle `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`?

Note: Current config in `.yaml` for consumer part looks like this:

```
spring:
 kafka:
  admin:
    fail-fast: true
  consumer:
    key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
    value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer      
    auto-startup: true
    max-poll-records: 2500
    group-id: some-group-name
    properties:
      allow.auto.create.topics: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not good practice to put consumers on different topics in the same group, because a rebalance on one topic causes an unnecessary rebalance for the other consumers.

A cooperative assignor might improve things, but it's still better to put them in different groups.

With modern versions of the framework, you rarely need multiple container factories because many of the common properties (group.id, client.id, etc) can be overridden in the annotation.

See the javadocs for `containerGroup`; it has no relation to `group.id`.

It is simply a way to define a group of containers (a `ContainerGroup` bean) that you might use to stop/start as a group (a subset of all containers).

`concurrency * maxInstances`  must be less than or equal to the number of partitions in a topic to avoid idle containers with no assigned partitions.